# Does an initialized Array retain its order?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Say that I initialize an Array somewhat like this:

```
int[] anArray = { 
    100, 200, 300,
    400, 500, 600, 
    700, 800, 900, 1000
};
```

Is it guaranteed that the elements will be always inserted in the same order I've typed on the initialization? E.g.: `100,200,300,400,500,600,700,...,1000`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes this is guaranteed by the specification (see [JLS 10.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)):

> The variable initializers immediately enclosed by the braces of the
>   array initializer are then executed from left to right in the textual
>   order they occur in the source code. The n'th variable initializer
>   specifies the value of the n-1'th array component.

Comment: Good! I was looking for something like that in the docs, guess I did look in the wrong page. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12):

Short answer: Yes, if you initialize it like that, they will be in the order as initialized.

See the JLS about that:

> The variable initializers immediately enclosed by the braces of the array initializer are then executed from left to right in the textual order they occur in the source code. The n'th variable initializer specifies the value of the n-1'th array component

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6

Answer (score 3):

> Is it guaranteed that the elements will be always inserted in the same order I've typed on the initialization?

Yes

Answer (score 1):

### YES!

The code you posted is identical to this :

```
int[] anArray = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000 };
```

What this does, is create an `array` of `integers`, where 100 goes at position 0, 200 to position 1, 300 to position 2 , 400 to position 3, etc.

This works the same for every array every time!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the array was changing the position of the values then most programs in the modern day will not work.

Comment: the OP is asking about the initialisation order and not the "position"