# Does an Initialized Array retain its order in C/C++ and similar languages?

Tags: java, c++, c, arrays, programming-languages

**Say that I have an Array in C/C++:**

```
int myArray[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

**Same in Java:**

```
int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

And the equivalent in other programming languages.

Is it guaranteed that the elements will be always in the same order I've typed on the initialization? E.g.: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`.

---

**Note:** I've already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733278/does-an-initialized-array-retain-its-order) specific to the Java programming language and I know it's true. But I wonder if this behavior is a rule for any (or most of) the programming languages, and I wasn't sure if an edit was the best way to ask that.

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed (as far as I know)

Comment: It would be very difficult to program in a language where that wasn't guaranteed.

Comment: Indeed it would. Good point.

Comment: @everyone : is there any reason for which they may be inserted in another order ? (eventually langage depedant)

Comment: This was a discussion I had with some colleagues, and I wasn't 100% if this was true.

Comment: @Pierre Maybe c++ or java wants to troll us

Comment: I think if the behaviour was anything else it wouldn't get called an array.

Comment: If you use correct containers, yes. With some *dictionary*, it would be a different story.

Comment: Please ask two separate questions, one for Java, one for C++.

Comment: @Jarod42 Maybe that's why one of my friends said that it was not always true.

Comment: @Jarod42 what do you mean by container?

Comment: What do you mean by "inserted"? Array elements don't get inserted.

Comment: Do arrays maintain their order, on the bedpost overnight?

Comment: perhaps the Befunge language could be said to be a language in which arrays don't keep their order. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge

Comment: @Blackbelt: As OP talks about *"for any (or most of) the programming languages"*, I group built-in array with more dedicated class/struct/.. of the language to handle that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

let us hear what the creators of C have to say about this:

> An array may be initialized by following its declaration with a list
>   of initializers enclosed in braces and separated by commas. For
>   example, to initialize an array days with the number of days in each
>   month: 
> `int days[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 }`
>   
>  When the size of the array is omitted, the compiler will compute the
>   length by counting the initializers, of which there are 12 in this
>   case. If there are fewer initializers for an array than the specified
>   size, the others will be zero for external, static and automatic
>   variables. It is an error to have too many initializers. 
> There is no
>   way to specify repetition of an initializer, nor to initialize an
>   element in the middle of an array without supplying all the preceding
>   values as well. 
> Character arrays are a special case of initialization;
>   a string may be used instead of the braces and commas notation: 
> `char pattern = "ould";` is a shorthand for the longer but equivalent
>  `char pattern[] = { 'o', 'u', 'l', 'd', '\0' };` In this case, the array size
>   is five (four characters plus the terminating '\0').

C BY BRIAN W KERNIGHAN & DENNIS M RITCHIE, second edition, page 95.

Comment: If you are quoting, please indicate what exactly are you quoting.

Comment: thx, i was about to but forgot to.

Answer (score 2):

> It will be same in both the case

`int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };`

It will just do

```
int[0] = 1
int[1] = 2
.
.
.
int[9] = 10
```

It will not vary to language to language `int[] array` is ideal in `java` just for program convenience `int array[]` is allowed.